# Javascript Infovis Doubly-Linked Nodes

Tags: javascript, canvas, directed-graph, infovis

I am using the Javscript InfoVis toolkit. Thanks, by the way, to whoever developed it. It is awesome. Anyways, I have two issues. I have a digraph being plotted from information parsed out of a .dot file, and some of the nodes need to be A) doubly-linked, or I need to have both edges `A->B` and `B->A` showing on the graph, and B) able to have slef-referential edges displayed.

A) I think that the graph is automatically checking for existence of edges between `A-B` in any direction before it plots new edges, and sees that `A->B` already exists and is not plotting `B->A`. I do know that `B->A` is in fact not being plotted at all in this case. I am currently looking in the jit.js core for the check to fix it. Also, if I do get the return edge to display, how can I curve the edges slightly so that I can see both of them in the graph? I am thinking there may be something I can implement in the `onBeforePlotLine:` section of jit.js.

B) I think that the solution to the curving of edges in A) will grant me the ability to show the self-referential edge. This edge is in fact being plotted, but is not visible due to the fact that it's start and finish points are the same.

If anyone has any experience solving either of these problems, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice. I found the class RGraph.EdgeTypes. Looks like you can implement all kinds of stuff there. I am going to start working on it now. If anyone has already implemented a slightly curved arrow, please save me the time, as it may take me a bit. Any other ideas are also appreicated! Thanks